# Consuming a Soa webservice with URL in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web-services, soap

I am consuming a web service in my windows forms application by adding a web reference, for which I have the url stored in a database. Now that the endpoint url has been updated, I am wondering if I should update my reference within the solution or update the url in the database should be enough?

```
 var addressService = new verify_client_ep();
 addressService.url= objServiceURL.Table[0].WS_URL.ToString();
```

Please provide me with a solution.

Comment: I was not talking anything to be changed in the web service, instead I was asking about the consuming a service in my windows forms solution instead of normal url, I stored url in database and now that the url was changed for the service without any changes to the contracts. my question  was is it enough if I update by url in the database or should I update my web reference in windows forms solution. wcf has nothing to do with this

Comment: added some code if that helps. I tried the best way I could. I am consuming an external web service for which they have changed the url which I stored in my database. will updating the url to the new url suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am consuming an external web service for which they have changed the url which I stored in my database. will updating the url to the new url suffice?

If they didn't change anything else but the endpoint, then yes.